# XSLT: Get the index of parent

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an XSLT file

```
<xsl: for-each select = "Parent1/Parent2">
    <xsl: value-of select = "Child_1">
    <xsl: value-of select = "Child_2">
</xsl: for-each>
```

Here in this case both the child element Child_1 and Child_2 will be added to final xml file.

I need to print Child_2 only when the index of Parent2 is say,4

How can I achieve that

Here is the input xml

```
<Parent1>
<Parent2>
    <Child_1>Child 1.1</Child_1>
    <Child_2>Child 1.2</Child_2>
</Parent2>
<Parent2>
    <Child_1>Child 2.1</Child_1>
    <Child_2>Child 2.2</Child_2>
</Parent2>
<Parent2>
    <Child_1>Child 3.1</Child_1>
    <Child_2>Child 3.2</Child_2>
</Parent2>
<Parent2>
    <Child_1>Child 4.1</Child_1>
    <Child_2>Child 4.2</Child_2>
</Parent2>
<Parent2>
    <Child_1>Child 5.1</Child_1>
    <Child_2>Child 5.2</Child_2>
</Parent2>
<Parent2>
    <Child_1>Child 6.1</Child_1>
    <Child_2>Child 6.2</Child2>
</Parent2>
</Parent1>

As an output I want
Child_1 1.1
Child_1 2.1
Child_1 3.1
Child_1 4.1
Child_2 4.2
Child_1 5.1
Child_1 6.1
```

Comment: You probably want to do `<xsl:for-each select = "Parent1/Parent2[4]">` but can you show a sample of you input XML, just to make sure. Thanks.

Comment: In that case Parent2 of index 4 will be selected ONLY and no others

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear, esp. the "*index of*" part. "*Index of Parent2*" in what group? -- Also please indicate which version of XSLT (the `index-of()` function is only available in XSLT 2.0).

Comment: Your sample output shows no instance of a `Child_2` at all - what exactly are you trying to do? Have you made a mistake - where it says `Child_1 4.2` should that in fact be `Child_2 4.2`?

Comment: Yeah that was a typing mistake...corrected it!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this could work for you:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Parent1/Parent2">
    <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
    <xsl:value-of select="Child_1"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="Child_2[$i=4]"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

It assumes you want to output the value of `Child_2` only when the position of `Parent2` in the (entire) node-set selected by the expression `Parent1/Parent2` is 4.

Comment: Thanks for answer michael. Iwill check it out. I have made edit in question...If you want to look at the xml files

Comment: @OldMonk My concerns are that (a) there could be more than one `Parent1` node and (b) a `Parent1` node could have other child nodes besides  `Parent2`. Any one of these would cause this problem to become not well-defined.